# Info regarding v8 internals

Tags: v8

how to debug built-in js files in v8.(i.e v8natives.js,array.js,string.js)

Please let me know any documentations or insights regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `%GlobalPrint("hello");`, the argument must be converted to a string before you pass it (So don't call `%GlobalPrint(1)` but `%GlobalPrint("1")` and it only takes one argument.

List of the functions you can call is at runtime/runtime.h (with their implementations and possibly some documentation in the runtime .cc files), these are on top of the normal javascript functions you can call like `JSON.parse`.

For example in the apinatives.js file:

```
function InstantiateFunction(data, name) {
  // We need a reference to kApiFunctionCache in the stack frame
  // if we need to bail out from a stack overflow.
  %GlobalPrint("Called instantiate function with ");
  %DebugPrint(data);
  %GlobalPrint("and");
  %DebugPrint(name);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing info. I have gone through the runtime functions 
and how they are called.
List of runtime functions that are used
https://gist.github.com/totherik/3a4432f26eea1224ceeb

when running simple js file with trace parse option 
(i.e out/ia32.debug/d8 1.js  --trace_parse)

Comment: we can see 
[parsing function: Instantiate - took 0.276 ms]
[parsing function: InstantiateFunction - took 0.343 ms]
[parsing function: ConfigureTemplateInstance - took 0.318 ms]
[parsing function: DefaultNumber - took 0.156 ms]
[parsing function: valueOf - took 0.037 ms]
[parsing function: IsPrimitive - took 0.038 ms]
[parsing function: toString - took 0.037 ms]
[parsing function: FunctionSourceString - took 0.257 ms]
[parsing script: 1.js - took 0.082 ms]

Comment: i.e instantiate,instantiate function all are part of apinatives.js
later actually my script is being evaluated.
can you please let me know how to check what are the values passed to that functions
and from where.How to debug those with some simple examples.

Thanks

Comment: @learner I added example, DebugPrint will print more info if you build debug binaries

Comment: Thanks for reply.
could you explain few things in detail.
(i.e simple addition script print(a+b)).
At each stage what exactly happens.
when i see before executing my simple script manythings happen.
Thanks in advance